# Can I just change the whole subplot for a new character?

Tags: fantasy, pov, chapters, subplot, first-time-author

I have a side character that I'm writing the POV of and their story just opened up so many possibilities for the story. I don't know what happens after this story, but so far it has all been rated E for everyone. If I go with the plot line I'm thinking of, however, I would need to change that to at least a 13+. Should I go with it or think of a different plot that fits the story better?
Story Link:
https://www.tumblr.com/blog/testingforhope

Answer (score 2):

You say rated E, but who is your target audience? Many books for adults are rated E, simply because there is no sex or violence in them, and yet children aren't interested in them and wouldn't understand them. So who are your writing for? If you write for teens or adults anyway, the change in rating is irrelevant.

As for whether that side story fits your main story, see the answer by EDL.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are answering your own question when you ask 'Should I go with it or think of a different plot that fits the story better?'

I conclude that you feel what you are writing doesn't fit the story you intended to tell. That is not uncommon. Sometimes writers find another story inside the story they set out to write; something that really resonates with their imagination. If that is the case, then change the rest of the story to align with that new motif -- for lack of a better word.

It may also be that this side character is an idea for a different story. In this case, you'd change the character or their arc inside your work in progress and save this plot for a different story.

When you write anything -- a novel, a short story, a grocery list -- there is no need to get it all right in the first draft.  Writing is revision. When you finish the whole draft, then you can read it through and see what belongs and what doesn't belong

Comment: I know i should have mentioned this a little earlier, but the reason I was asking this question is because the chapters are already getting posted after they are written. I post it with the intention of mimicking fanfiction.